# How could I read this txt file in R?

Tags: r

I have a very simple txt file but I could not open it in R.

```
"x"  
"1" 27.5900001525879  
"2" 27.0799999237061  
"3" NA  
"4" NA  
"5" NA  
"6" 27.7999992370605  
"7" 27.7099990844727  
"8" 27.3899993896484  
"9" NA   
"10"    NA    
"11"    28.7199993133545    
"12"    NA  
"13"    NA  
"14"    NA  
"15"    NA  
"16"    27.6599998474121  
"17"    NA  
"18"    27.9500007629395  


> data <- read.table(text="mydata.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
> data
[1] mydata.txt
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specify a filename, you have to use `file` instead of `text`:

```
read.table(file = "mydata.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

But I recommend omitting all additional arguments, i.e.:

```
read.table(file = "mydata.txt")
```

This will read the row names (between quotation marks) as row names:

```
       x
1  27.59
2  27.08
3     NA
4     NA
5     NA
6  27.80
7  27.71
8  27.39
9     NA
10    NA
11 28.72
12    NA
13    NA
14    NA
15    NA
16 27.66
17    NA
18 27.95
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
da <- read.table(file="mydata.txt", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, sep=" ")
da
```

file= rather than text=
fill=TRUE
I changed separator to " ", but if there are actual tabs in your file, leave as "\t"